# How do I draw a line outwards from the exact middle of a rectangle's edge, and combine the paths in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, shapes, path

I want to draw this shape in Inkscape:

[image]

The line coming from the side needs to be aligned to exactly the middle of the edge, coming out at a right angle.

It must also be part of the rectangle object, so that when I alter the color or width of the line, I don't have to do it separately for either object (the line and the rectangle).

**What is the simplest way of drawing a line outwards from the centre of a rectangles edge, and then combining the paths, in Inkscape?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Align and distribute

1. Draw a stroke and a box in random order

   [image]
2. Select stroke to make it horizontal by adjusting its height to `0` in the top toolbar

   [image]
3. Adjust stroke style width (*Object > Fill and Strike*) to desired values

   [image]
4. Choose *Object > Align and Distribute* tool

   - relative to biggest object (or first selected depending on workflow)
   - align *right edges of the object to left edges of the anchor*
   - align *center on the horizontal axis*

   [image]

   [image]
5. Select both the line and the box to then choose *Object > Group* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>
6. Now changing fill or stroke of this group will affect all children

   [image]